# Where should I put my ag-grid code?

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I have a single view containing an ag-grid and a single controller for my angular application. I'm trying to clean up the controller, to make it 'thin', and I've already moved some code away in a directive, and I've set up services for the data retrieval.

Now I'm left with a big blog of ag-grid code which I'd ideally like to see squirrelled somewhere else, but I'm unsure where would be the best place.

Is there a best practise here?

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="MainController">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div>
            <div ag-grid="gridOptions" class="ag-fresh" style="height: 500px; width: 100%"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div my-directive body-unid="currentUNID"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular);
```

angular.module('app')
    .controller('MainController', function ($scope, myService, MyConfig) {

```
    $scope.isExternalFilterPresent = function () {
        return $scope.searchtext != "";
    };

    $scope.doesExternalFilterPass = function (node) {

        // Returning true means all the documents are displayed
        if ($scope.searchtext == "") {
            return true;
        }

        if ($scope.joinedUnidsOfSearch) {
            return ($scope.joinedUnidsOfSearch.indexOf(node.data['@unid']) >= 0);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    };

    var columnDefs = [
        {
            headerName: "Navigation", field: "Subject", cellStyle: function (params) {
            if (params.data["@indent"]) {
                switch (params.data["@indent"]) {
                    case 1:
                        return {'margin-left': '10px'};
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        return {'margin-left': '20px'};
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        return {'margin-left': '30px'};
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        return {'margin-left': '40px'};
                        break;
                    default:
                        return {'margin-left': '50px'};
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                return {'font-size': 'large'};
            }
        }
            //, headerName: "unid", field: "@unid"
        }
    ];

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: columnDefs,
        rowSelection: 'single',
        enableFilter: true,
        isExternalFilterPresent: $scope.isExternalFilterPresent,
        doesExternalFilterPass: $scope.doesExternalFilterPass,

        angularCompileRows: true,
        onRowClicked: function (event) {
            //console.log('a row was clicked', event.data["@unid"]);
            $scope.currentUNID = event.data["@unid"];
            $scope.$apply();
        },
        onColumnResized: function (event) {
            //console.log('a column was resized');
        },
        onGridReady: function (event) {
            //console.log('the grid is now ready');
        },

        // onRowSelected: rowSelected,
        // onSelectionChanged: onSelectionChanged,

        onGridSizeChanged: function () {
            //console.log('Grid Size changed');
            $scope.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
        }
    };

    $scope.databaseTitle = MyConfig.databaseTitle;

    $scope.SearchButtonClick = function () {
        $scope.searchComment = '';
        loadSearchResults($scope);
    };

    $scope.ClearSearchBox = function () {
        $scope.searchtext = '';
        $scope.searchComment = '';
        $scope.gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged();
    };


    $scope.NextButtonClick = function () {
        //console.log("next button clicked");
        var selectedNodes = $scope.gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes();
        if (selectedNodes) {
            if (selectedNodes && selectedNodes.length === 1) {
                var selectedNode = selectedNodes[0];
                $scope.gridOptions.api.forEachNodeAfterFilter(function (node) {
                    if (node.childIndex === (selectedNode.childIndex + 1)) {
                        node.setSelected(true);
                        $scope.currentUNID = node.data["@unid"];
                        return;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.PrevButtonClick = function () {
        //console.log("next button clicked");
        var selectedNodes = $scope.gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes();
        if (selectedNodes) {
            if (selectedNodes && selectedNodes.length === 1) {
                var selectedNode = selectedNodes[0];
                $scope.gridOptions.api.forEachNodeAfterFilter(function (node) {
                    if (node.childIndex === (selectedNode.childIndex - 1)) {
                        node.setSelected(true);
                        $scope.currentUNID = node.data["@unid"];
                        return;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };

    function loadSearchResults($scope) {
        //console.log('loadSearchResults started');
        if ($scope.searchtext) {
            myService.loadAllUNIDSThatMatchSearch($scope.searchtext).then(function (data) {
                //console.log('start after loading of search UNIDS');
                var receiveddata = angular.fromJson(data);
                if (receiveddata) {
                    if (receiveddata.length > 0) {
                        $scope.searchComment = '';
                        var arrayUNIDS = receiveddata.map(function (a) {
                            return a["@unid"];
                        });
                        $scope.joinedUnidsOfSearch = arrayUNIDS.join(); // this variable gets used in the function doesExternalFilterPass
                        $scope.gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged(); // refreshes filter of grid
                        // set the selected document to the first of the search query
                        $scope.gridOptions.api.forEachNodeAfterFilter(function (node) {
                            if (node.firstChild === true) {
                                // node.setSelected(true);
                                $scope.gridOptions.api.selectNode(node, true);
                                $scope.currentUNID = node["@unid"];
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        if ($scope.searchtext == '' || $scope.searchtext == undefined) {
                            $scope.searchComment = 'Das Suchfeld ist leer!';
                        } else {
                            $scope.searchComment = 'Keine Dokumenten für ' + $scope.searchtext + ' gefunden.';
                        }


                    }
                }
                //console.log('end after loading of search UNIDS');
            });
        }
        //console.log('loadSearchResults ended');
    }

    myService.loadAllNavigationDocuments()
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(response);
        });


});
```

Comment: Could you share some code? I always use angular components for that.

Comment: done. I know it's ugly right now!

Comment: I tried to move the code away in another controller, but then I had the issue that I was having problems accessing the $scope

Answer (score 1):

Now, seeing your code i think you can to move all grid stuff to a service.
In the service create methods and call then in your controller like that:

```
//create the event "onGridSizeChanged" for the grid
gridService.onGridSizeChanged($scope.gridOptions, fuction(options){
   //callback for size changed
});
```

Just an example, so create all other method you need. Your controller will be clean and you can use that service in other controllers. Wich method has one responsability and it's easy to maintain.

Comment: So I'm defining gridOptions in my controller?

Comment: yes, you defined gridOptios in your controller and handle other methods and events inside a angular service.

Comment: I've been successful in putting columnDefs in my Service, however I'm blocking for instance with the function doesExternalFilterPass. It needs a node parameter, and once I move the function to the service I get complaints that $scope is not known. I think I'm missing something very basic here.

Comment: I think those functions **doesExternalFilterPass** and **isExternalFilterPresent** aren't funcitons used on grid right? If not, create then in $scope and not in gridOptions. Leave gridOptions just for grid properties/methods

Comment: They're members of gridOptions used for filtering

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether the code you're showing here (the gridService.OnGridSizeChanged) is within my controller or my service.

Comment: Ok, so the gridOptions definition must be in controller $scope. But you can or not define your methods inside the service or not. My suggestion is you define all the method inside the service. I will edit my answer above for a full solution.